# SAML SSO request with redirect response to local private IP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a situation where I need to authenticate my application users with  SAML2.0. SAML server is hosted at a public domain while our application runs in local intranet.

I wonder, if SAML would support redirecting my users back to the local application (local IP) after authentication.

This is by default or is there any special configuration need to be done in SAML server side?

Comment: The SAML server on the public domain, is it in the identity provider role, or the service provider role? I presume that your users can access the private domain...

Comment: SAML server is identity provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is being accessed from the local intranet, it will definitely work. There won't be any additional configuration required for that. The reason is simple - SAML uses HTTP Redirects and Form-Post to pass SAML tokens. So if the two applications (IdP and SP) are accessible, it will work.

I have an ADFS server on Azure (available publicly) and the SP is in my local development environment (accessible only on my laptop). It works.

Comment: In addition to above question.. In a scenario, like if authentication required for the application, (not for the user) can SAML provide a way to authenticate using a background task (eg: REST like service) without redirecting the user back and forth?

Comment: No. SAML won't work with the Rest APIs. It needs HTTP Redirects or Post request as it depends on the Browser sessions. There are other protocols like OAuth, OpenID Connect, JWT in which you can redirect user to IdP (just once) and get the token and use that token to authenticate your application in all the subsequent Rest service calls (as the Authorization Header). If the token expires, you can call the refresh token API of your IdP. But of course, this depends if your IdP supports these protocols. For example, Azure AD supports SAML as well as JWT.

Answer (score 2):

SAML protocol provides the 'RelayState' request parameter for certain bindings. E.g. have a a loot at http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf

This allows to specify a target URL for your application acting as SAML SP.